# How do I connect a html search bar to a sharepoint library?

Tags: search, search-results, custom-actions, content-search-web-part

My client asked me for creating a fancy html landing page with a fancy SearchBar, and its done

This bar has to find files in a specific  sharepoint library.

How can I make the custom search bar to fin files in a sharepoint library ? 
Please help!!!

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a SharePoint page with Two webpart, once is SearchBox and another is Search result webpart. UI you can always modify using with help of Javascript,Jquery and CSS.

ref for Searchbox style change :[How to change the style of the Search box?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11529/how-to-change-the-style-of-the-search-box)

ref :https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search-box-web-part?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252f1915c232-3a41-440a-b5be-b1cdf364b607

In Search Result webpart you can define result Source for your webpart which will only Document Library which you mentioned.

ref :https://support.office.com/en-us/article/change-settings-for-the-search-results-web-part-40ff85b3-bc5e-4230-b1dd-f088188e487e

Thanks,

Comment: Thank you so much! it really helped me to finish my task!!